# Como trazer todos os resultados da API

Tags: angular, api, typescript, rest

Estou aprendendo Angular e para isso venho desenvolvendo o tutorial Tour of Heroes da própria documentação em [Tutorial: Tuor of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0), mas estou tentando aplicar algumas funcionalidades à mais através desta [API de Heróis](https://superheroapi.com/ids.html). Eu já consegui construir uma lista com o id e nome destes herois, mas está retornando apenas 27 resultados. Como faço para exibir todos os mais de 700 heróis da API?

lista-herois.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Heroi } from './heroi';
import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListaHeroisService {

private readonly API = 'https://superheroapi.com/api/5033128890082701/search/id'



constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

list() {
  
  return this.http.get<Heroi[]>(this.API)
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log)
  )
}


}
```

dashboard.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Heroi } from './heroi';
import { ListaHeroisService } from './lista-herois.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  

  herois!: Heroi[];

  constructor(private service: ListaHeroisService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.service.list().subscribe((herois:any)=>{
    this.herois = herois.results;
    })
  }

}
```

heroi.ts

```
export interface Heroi {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    image: { 
        url: string },
    powerstats: {
        id: string,
        name: string,
        intelligence: string,
        strength: string,
        speed: string,
        durability: string,
        power: string,
        combat: string
    },
    appearance: {
        response: string,
        id: string,
        name: string,
        gender: string,
        race: string,
        height: [
          string,
          string
        ],
        weight: [
          string,
          string
        ],
        ['eye-color']: string,
        ['hair-color']: string
      }
   }
```

dashboard.components.html

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let heroi of herois">
    <span class="badge">{{heroi.id}}</span> {{heroi.name}}
  </li>
</ul>



<ul class="heroisList" *ngFor="let heroi of herois">  
  <li>
  
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{heroi.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ heroi.name }}</h5>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Gênero: {{heroi.appearance.gender}}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Raça: {{heroi.appearance.race}}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Nível de Poder: {{heroi.powerstats.power}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Resultado atual:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem um outro endereço que consome esta API onde tem uma lista com todos. Veja se este link te ajuda https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/akabab/superhero-api@0.3.0/api/all.json

Comment: Nossa! Muito obrigado. Fucionou sim, mas minha dúvida agora é como você obteve este link. O que preciso considerar numa próxima ocasião como essa?

Comment: A chamada que você faz à api na verdade são todos os personagens que possuem "id" no nome. Leia a documentação da api. Ela não não fornece a lista em nenhum endpoint, mas tem uma tabela no site deles que serve de base para você montar manualmente um array com a lista completa de ids

Comment: Perfeito! Entendi a lógica agora. Preciso então dar uma estuda em laços de repetição para armazenar os IDs no Array Heroi[]?

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente seu código está correto. No caso, o problema é a api.

se o link da documentação for esse mesmo: [https://superheroapi.com/][1]

a api não oferece recurso para listar todos. Apenas lista heróis filtrados pelo nome e/ou outras categorias.

o parâmetro /search/ indica que você vai fazer uma pesquisa escrita e o /id/ que você colocou, indica a referência. Então ele vai buscar na base, todos os heróis que tiverem id no nome.

exemplo: Billy Kinca***id***

Comment: Sim, o link da documentação é este mesmo. Acredito então que preciso criar uma funcão para pegar todos os IDS da lista

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).